# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el estilo del StatusBar a blanco dentro de un UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Utilize el siguiente codigo para cambiar el estilo del statusbar(Operador,Hora,Bateria) y si me funciono. El color de la barra cambia a blanco.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el Problema que tengo es que al agregar un NavigationController el estilo del StatusBar regresa a default de color negro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Cómo podria hacer para cambiar ese estilo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos utilizar la propiedad `barStyle` con el valor `.black` , `.blackOpaque`o `.blackTranslucent`  y con `barTintColor` podriamos personalizar el color de la barra .

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.brown

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Tambien se puede cambiar el valor de las propiedades en las opciones del `NavigationBar`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia :
**Documentation and API Reference**
Personalización de la apariencia de una barra de navegación

Las barras de navegación tienen dos estilos de aspecto estándar: blanco con texto oscuro o negro con texto claro. Utilice la propiedad `barStyle` para seleccionar el estilo. Cualquier cambio que realice en otras propiedades de apariencia de la barra de navegación reemplaza a los inferidos del estilo de barra.

Las barras de navegación son translúcidas por defecto; Es decir, su color de fondo es semitransparente. Puede hacer la barra de navegación opaca estableciendo la propiedad `isTranslucent` a `false`.

Puede especificar un color de tinte personalizado para un fondo de barra de navegación utilizando la propiedad `barTintColor`. La configuración de esta propiedad reemplaza el color predeterminado deducido del estilo de barra. Como con todas las subclases de `UIView`, puede controlar el color de los elementos interactivos dentro de las barras de navegación, incluyendo imágenes de botón y títulos, utilizando la propiedad `tintColor`.

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que el nuevo `UINavigationController` sea el `rootViewController` de tu aplicación.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) -> Bool {
    self.window.rootViewController = navController
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```